# Confusion when installing a supported ROS robot

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I have finished with the basic tutorials and want to start work on an AR. Drone. From the ROS page, it has directed me to follow this tutorial:

link:[text](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy#updates)

My initial confusion is at the beginning where it says

> Please make sure that this folder is in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environmental variable.

yet the first line of code says:

```
cd ~/ros/stacks
```

My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH does not have a stacks (/opt/ros/fuerte has a stacks folder however). Should I be installing this code in the /opt... path or should I make a new folder in my sandbox directory which is what I did for my beginner tutorials?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73057/confusion-when-installing-a-supported-ros-robot/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put your code in your sandbox folder, which in this example was named ~/ros/stacks.

Never put any user code in /opt/...

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-08-15**:
Thank you very much!!